# I want to loop setTimeout() function after every 22 seconds

Tags: javascript, settimeout

I have a JAVASCRIPT code I want to loop this code after every 22 seconds. Can you help me with this, please?

It is the code.

```
setTimeout(function() {
  $('#hideMe01').fadeOut('fast');
}, 8000);

setTimeout(function() {
  $('#hideMe02').fadeOut('fast');
}, 8000);

setTimeout(function() {
  $('#hideMe03').fadeOut('fast');
}, 14000);

setTimeout(function() {
  $('#hideMe04').fadeOut('fast');
}, 14000);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just wrap the whole thing in an interval...

```
function doFade(){
    setTimeout(function() {
      $('#hideMe01').fadeOut('fast');
    }, 8000);

    setTimeout(function() {
      $('#hideMe02').fadeOut('fast');
    }, 8000);

    setTimeout(function() {
      $('#hideMe03').fadeOut('fast');
    }, 14000);

    setTimeout(function() {
      $('#hideMe04').fadeOut('fast');
    }, 14000);

    setTimeout(doFade,22000);
}
doFade();
```

Comment: Why is that, it runs fine  when I do a quick test?

Comment: Let me test it please

Comment: ahh, you're refering to the typo at the end.  I thought you had spotted some kind of logical error.  Fixed the typo.

Comment: Try it now, there was a typo I hadn't noticed that's been fixed.

Comment: I've changed it around so that it will run the first time as well.

Comment: See this is not working perfectly on my slider. As you see the first slider is working perfectly fine but I want a loop so I want the second slider also should work as the first is working. Can you help with it :) https://www.dropbox.com/s/hx0ruupnimgkyep/slider.zip?dl=0

Comment: can you help me please?